# SQL - list of products that have been bought together

Tags: c#, sql, .net-core

I need a SQL query to find out which products have been bought together with other products in the same order.

I have this table:

| orderId | productId |
| --- | --- |
| A111 | 1 |
| A111 | 21 |
| A111 | 12 |
| A111 | 31 |
| A122 | 21 |
| A122 | 43 |
| A122 | 32 |
| A122 | 1 |
| A333 | 12 |
| A333 | 64 |
| A333 | 63 |
| A333 | 21 |
| A333 | 12 |

And I want a query that gives me this:

| productId | bought together with (productId) |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 12 |
| 1 | 21 |
| 1 | 31 |
| 1 | 64 |
| 1 | 63 |
| 21 | 1 |
| 21 | 12 |
| 21 | 31 |
| 12 | 1 |
| 12 | 21 |
| 12 | 31 |
| and so on... |  |

I have tried to do a GroupBy and a cursor, but I can't find a solution.

Or is there any how to do this in a C# .NET Core app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a self-join:

```
select distinct t1.productid, t2.productid
from t t1 join
     t t2
     on t1.orderid = t2.orderid
where t1.productid <> t2.productid;
```

If you have a table of products, you could also phrase this as:

```
select p1.productid, p2.productid
from products p1 cross join
     products p2
where exists (select 1
              from t t1 join
                   t t2
                   on t1.orderid = t2.orderid
              where t1.productid = p1.productid and
                    t2.productid = p2.productid
             );
```

Comment: This query is taking a lot of time... is there any other that is faster?

Comment: @DonJuan . . . The `select distinct` is probably the cause of the performance issue.  I suggested an alternative formulation.

Comment: I did the changes, I guess you forgot the "on" statement in join:

select p1.ProductId, p2.ProductId
from ProductTable p1 join
     ProductTable p2
  on p1.ProductId= p2.ProductId
where exists (select 1
              from OrderHistoryItem t1 join
                   OrderHistoryItem t2
                   on t1.OrderHistory_id = t2.OrderHistory_id
              where t1.ProductId = p1.ProductId and
                    t2.ProductId = p2.ProductId 
             )

????
It doesnt work

Comment: @DonJuan . . . That was intended to be `cross join`.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this:

```
SELECT a.productId AS item_1,
       b.productId AS item_2,
COUNT(*) AS times_bought_together
FROM your_table_name a
JOIN your_table_name b
ON a.orderId = b.orderId
WHERE a.productId > b.productId 
GROUP BY a.productId, b.productId 
ORDER BY times_bought_together DESC
```

This also includes a column to show the frequency of the items that are bought together more frequently.

Just be careful as this may include some NONEs on the pairs. You could add more code to filter out the NONE values, but in my case it wasn't necessary since I only needed the top 3 pairs.

Comment: This also excludes repeated pairs like 1-12, 12-1. If you want it to show the repeated pairs, just add <> instead of > on the 'WHERE' line